# Inno-Setup checking file location prior to installation, then using it during installation

Tags: inno-setup

I need to check for the location of a file during program installation utilizing inno setup.  I then need inno setup to use the location of that file in the "Filename" line to create a desktop ICON for program initialization.  I have the code for the "Icons" option working fine with the exception of how to do the above.

Here is the line of code I am currently using;

```
Name: "{commondesktop}\SA - NH Bricscad V12"; Filename:"**c:\program files\septic assistant\new hampshire\support\**SA - NH Bricscad V12.exe"; IconFilename: "C:\Program Files\Septic Assistant\New Hampshire\Support\Bricscadlogo.ico"; Comment: "Septic Assistant the only Septic Design Program"
```

Hi-Lited section would be the path to the exe file that I need inno setup to search for.

Any assistance with this would be very much appreciated.

Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `{code:...}` constant and corresponding `[Code]` function that returns the appropriate path for your `[Icons]` entry.  You will probably also want to use a `Check` function to avoid installing the icon in the case that you cannot find the correct location.

Another option is to use a `{reg:...}` constant, assuming that the path you are trying to locate is specified somewhere in the registry (which is usually the case).

If the path is not already specified somewhere well-defined in the Registry when the other app is installed, and you don't have some other means to quickly identify where the other app is located (note that doing a global search of the user's HD is **not** a valid option), then you should add a page that prompts the user to enter the location themselves (which you can then verify that they have chosen the correct location).  You can see examples of prompting the user for information and then doing something with that info in the `CodeDlg.iss` example included with Inno, and in the ISXKB wiki.

Comment: +1, taking back what I wrote; nice to learn something new! Haven't seen this before. Is there an official page in help for this ?

Comment: @miral I am not a programer, and have no idea on Pascal Code.  I have created a variable with the "#define" called "Bricscaddir" and I have that variable for the "Filename" in the ICONS section.  All seems to work fine, however I need the code to find the "Bricscad.exe" directory for the [code] section.  Is there anyway you could help me out with that.

Comment: @TLama: code constants are documented in the help; you can use them pretty much anywhere that accept other constants (which are typically limited to places that accept strings and are only used at runtime).

Comment: @snownut2: It's probably a good idea to get the assistance of a programmer in your organisation -- customising installation often requires a bit of code, though it's fairly straightforward. My original answer assumed that you already had code that had found the correct path to use. I've updated it with another option if the path is specified somewhere in the registry.

Comment: @Miral: Well I found the answer to the issue, use the "useapppaths" flag on the ICON line, and all is great.